# Active Directory ADSync error with non-existent account

Tags: active-directory, powershell, entra-id, azureadconnect

I have a weird ADSync error stating that my local active directory contains two objects with the same ProxyAddress property. One of accounts is *username*@domain.tld (which is correct) and the second is *username*@domain.onmicrosoft.com (which is inexistent in AD in my opinion) - and, according to DirSync errors report, both of them contain the same conflicting ProxyAddress ***username*@domain.tld**. AzureAD shows that both accounts source from local Active Directory. The point is that someone could create *onmicrosoft.com account years ago to test office365.

I have checked two things so far:

1. Small powershell script to test for the same proxyaddress in local AD:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties proxyAddresses | foreach {
    foreach($address in $_.proxyAddresses) {
        if ($address -eq 'smtp:username@domain.tld') {
            Write-Host $address
        }
    }
 }
```

2. Checking for immutableIDs of conflicting accounts:

```
$user = Get-ADUser legit_account
$immutableid = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($user.ObjectGUID.tobytearray())
$immutableid #shows the same as legit account in DirSync report

$badImmutableID = 'base64 copied from bad account DirSync error report=='


$users = get-aduser -Filter *
foreach ($usr in $users) {
    $currImmutableID = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($usr.ObjectGUID.tobytearray())
    if ($currImmutableID -eq $badImmutableID) {
        $usr
    }
}
```

This script provides no output with bad immutableID (but works with others).

I am actually stuck at this point - AzureAD won't let me delete bad account to resolve conflict saying I have to solve it in local AD while there is no such account. Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable the AD synchronization before deleting that bad account,

**Step 1** – Install the Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell

```
Install-Module -Name MSOnline
Install-Module -Name AzureAD
```

**Step 2** – Connect to Azure AD

```
Connect-MsolService
```

**Step 3** – Disable Directory Synchronization

```
Set-MsolDirSyncEnabled –EnableDirSync $false
```

**Step 4** – Check Directory Synchronization Status

```
(Get-MSOLCompanyInformation).DirectorySynchronizationEnabled
```

Continue to run this cmdlet periodically until it returns False, and then go to the next step. Note that Azure AD won't be usable during this period of time.

**Step 5** – Delete the orphaned object

```
Remove-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName user@domain.onmicrosoft.com
```

**Step 6** – Enable Directory Synchronization

```
Set-MsolDirSyncEnabled -EnableDirSync $true
```

More info here: [You can't manage or remove objects that were synchronized through the Azure Active Directory Sync tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2619062/you-can-t-manage-or-remove-objects-that-were-synchronized-through-the)

**Edit: - WARNING:**  As pointed out by Cyrill U, enabling synchronization again can take up to 72 hours, so that has to be taken into account before this procedure.

**More info:** [Directory synchronization for Office 365, Azure, or Intune can't be activated or deactivated](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2654338/directory-synchronization-for-office-365-azure-or-intune-can-t-be-acti)

Comment: Thank you. At least it worked to step 5 - now I'm waiting to enable DirSync back at "You cannot turn off synchronization" error. Probably we should add a notification to someone who could also find the solution that MS won't allow turning DirSync on right after it has been turned off according to this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2654338/directory-synchronization-for-office-365-azure-or-intune-can-t-be-acti

Comment: You are absolutely right, I'll update the answer to reflect that caveat!